# Is there a way to preserve output cell scrolling when converting a Jupyter Notebook to HTML?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I like that output cell scrolling allows me to contain a lot of information in a small space. But if I convert my notebook to HTML, the doc doesn't have the scrolling. Is there a way to preserve this formatting in the converted doc?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

This happens with both `nbconvert` and Download As HTML.

Also, if there was a way to preserve the original shading and other formatting details, I would appreciate hearing that as well.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @ateymour no, sadly